# How to symlink files in folders

Tags: files, scripting, directory, symlink

Iterate over files in folder and creating symlinks:

I have the current script that is trying to iterate over files in a folder, and create symlinks into another folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
############################
# .make.sh
# This script creates symlinks from the home directory to any desired dotfiles in ~/dotfiles
############################

########## Variables

dir=~/dotfiles                    # dotfiles directory
config_files=$dir/*

# move any existing home files in homedir to dotfiles_old directory, then create symlinks
for config_file in $config_files; do
  ln -s $dir/$config_file ~/.$config_file
done
```

Now, if in my ~/dotfiles I have more than files, for example, I have folders with files in it. How can I make sure that I create the folders as well as do the symlinking?

So, for example, in my `~/dotfiles` I have:

`~/dotfiles/.config/fish/config.fish` and `~/dotfiles/.config/fish/conf.d/config.fish`

I should finish with a symlink to

`~/.config/fish/config.fish` and `~/.config/fish/conf.d/config.fish`

How can I do that?

Comment: augh quote those variables in the event a space sneaks into a filename

Comment: What's wrong with symlinks to directories?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use `cp` instead of `ln`. From [`man 1 cp`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cp):

> `-R`
> copy directories recursively
>
> `-s`
> make symbolic links instead of copying

Notes:

- `-R` is required by POSIX but `-s` is not (your `cp` may or may not support it).
- If you "copy" a file this way, `-R` won't hurt.
- `cp -Rs …` will replicate directory structure with symlinks to files (not symlinks to directories); it seems this is what you want.
- In my Kubuntu creating relative symlinks with `cp` is limited to the current directory, so it's useless with `-R`. Use full path to the directory you want to "copy".
- Research `-p` option of `cp`. I guess you want to use it.

---

Few concerns about your script:

- [This comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413898/how-to-symlink-files-in-folders#comment742626_413898) is wise; quote variables.
- `*` won't return files nor directories with names starting with a dot (`.`).

Comment: Good idea but this works only if the source dir is an absolute path. Otherwise you get `cp: targetdir/subdir/file2: can make relative symbolic links only in current directory`